# C Linux kernel module hook stat to hide directory

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, hook, rootkit

I've tried to hide folder `/home/xytao/safe` by adding module to kernel that hook `stat`, but when I return `-2`(ENOENT,No such file or directory), I can still use `cd /home/xytao/safe` to enter that folder.

Here is my module

```
asmlinkage long fake_stat(const char __user *filename, struct __old_kernel_stat __user *statbuf)
{
    if (!strncmp(filename,"/home/xytao/safe",16))
    {   
        return -2;
    }
    return real_stat(filename,statbuf);
}
```

Using `strace bash -c "cd /home/xytao/safe"` ,I can see the return value has been changed, which means this module is loaded fine, but it still go to the folder successfully. Here is the part of the strace output:

```
...
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/xytao", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/xytao/safe", 0x7ffd5104fd40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chdir("/home/xytao/safe")               = 0
brk(0x1e66000)                          = 0x1e66000
getcwd("/home/xytao/safe", 4096)        = 17
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Is that mean I need to hook `chdir` as well?

Comment: If you want the chdir to fail, yes. Note that your module also won't block "cd /home/xytao; cd safe", so if you want to actually hide it then your module needs to be a lot more advanced.

Comment: @immibis Can you explain what other system calls I need to modify to get this to work more advanced?

Comment: like, all of them... it's not the best way to hide something.

Comment: @immibis Well, then what's a better way to hide a directory in linux?

Comment: You don't. This isn't a desirable behavior.

Comment: If you want to hide a folder, hide it and its contents in a file, mounted via the loopback device (possibly via an encryption module). When not in use, don't mount it. (If you insist on doing it via a kernel module, you probably can [not going to help you there, however]; but doing this sort of stuff in userspace is a much better idea.)

Comment: I assume the reason for hiding a file is for learning, because it's not something that's very helpful... If you're learning to hook a syscall, congrats, you've done it (as we can tell by the strace).